# Comparing Dates in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date-comparison

I'm trying to get it to display the number of employees that are hired after June 20, 1994,

```
Select employee_id, count(*)
From Employee
Where to_char(employee_date_hired, 'DD-MON-YY') > 31-DEC-95;
```

But I get an error saying

> "JUN' invalid identifier.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Note also that you can use either `> <` or `BETWEEN '' AND ''`

Answer (score 367):

`31-DEC-95` isn't a string, nor is `20-JUN-94`. They're numbers with some extra stuff added on the end. This should be `'31-DEC-95'` or `'20-JUN-94'` - note the single quote, `'`. This will enable you to do a string comparison.

However, you're not doing a string comparison; *you're doing a date comparison*. You should transform your string into a date. Either by using the built-in [`TO_DATE()`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions219.htm#SQLRF06132) function, or a [date literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062).

### TO_DATE()

```
select employee_id
  from employee
 where employee_date_hired > to_date('31-DEC-95','DD-MON-YY')
```

This method has a few unnecessary pitfalls

- As a_horse_with_no_name noted in the comments, `DEC`, doesn't necessarily mean December. It depends on your [`NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm#i1006894) and [`NLS_DATE_FORMAT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm#i1006817) settings. To ensure that your comparison will work in any locale you can use the [datetime format model](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212) `MM` instead
- The year '95 is inexact. You know you mean 1995, but what if it was '50, is that 1950 or 2050? It's always best to be explicit

```
select employee_id
  from employee
 where employee_date_hired > to_date('31-12-1995','DD-MM-YYYY')
```

### Date literals

A date literal is part of the ANSI standard, which means you don't have to use an Oracle specific function. When using a literal you *must* specify your date in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` and you cannot include a time element.

```
select employee_id
  from employee
 where employee_date_hired > date '1995-12-31'
```

Remember that the Oracle date datatype includes a time element, so the date without a time portion is equivalent to `1995-12-31 00:00:00`.

If you want to include a time portion then you'd have to use a timestamp literal, which takes the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS[.FF0-9]`

```
select employee_id
  from employee
 where employee_date_hired > timestamp '1995-12-31 12:31:02'
```

### Further information

[`NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm#i1006894) is derived from [`NLS_LANGUAGE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm#i1006480) and [`NLS_DATE_FORMAT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm#i1006817) is derived from [`NLS_TERRITORY`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm#i1006575). These are set when you initially created the database but they can be altered by changing your initialization parameters file - only if really required - or at the session level by using the [`ALTER SESSION`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_2015.htm#SQLRF00901) syntax. For instance:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

This means:

- `DD` numeric day of the month, 1 - 31
- `MM` numeric month of the year, 01 - 12 ( January is 01 )
- `YYYY` 4 digit year - in my opinion this is *always* better than a 2 digit year `YY` as there is no confusion with what century you're referring to.
- `HH24` hour of the day, 0 - 23
- `MI` minute of the hour, 0 - 59
- `SS` second of the minute, 0-59

You can find out your current language and date language settings by querying `V$NLS_PARAMETERSs` and the full gamut of valid values by querying `V$NLS_VALID_VALUES`.

### Further reading

- [Format models](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212)

---

Incidentally, if you want the `count(*)` you need to group by `employee_id`

```
select employee_id, count(*)
  from employee
 where employee_date_hired > date '1995-12-31'
 group by employee_id
```

This gives you the count *per* `employee_id`.

Comment: +1 for using a format mask in to_date(). Note that this can still fail on a different environments due to different language settings. `DEC` is not necessarily always a valid month. It's usually better to use numbers instead of names

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for the point. I've updated with your suggestion.

Comment: You *can* specify a time with an ANSI literal - you just need to specify a `timestamp` literal instead of a `date` literal: `timestamp '2015-01-30 19:42:04'`  (because in ANSI SQL a the `date` data type doesn't have a time, only the `timestamp` data type does).

Comment: The  ANSI date literals is really a concise way comparing having to type TO_DATE and Date-Format every time. Good for **LAZY** developers like me. One thing to Notice is the `DATE 2016-04-01` means `2016-04-01 00:00:00` really. And I think this syntax works since **Oracle 9i** as this is where ANSI-SQL syntax was introduced into Oracle.

Comment: My thinking has evolved significantly in the last 4 years @Leon :-)' I've updated the answer. I had mentioned that a date literal didn't include a time element but I've called this out more explicitly as you've stated. 9i extended support ended almost 6 years ago... and was released 14 years ago. It shouldn't be relevant any more for the vast majority of users.

Comment: Is `alter session` equivalent to `define` somehow?

Comment: No, it's very different @Alireza. [`define` is a SQL*Plus command that substitutes whatever you've defined into all substitution variables with that name](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/define.html). [`ALTER SESSION` is a statement that allows you to modify some database parameters or settings for the duration of that session](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_2015.htm#SQLRF00901)

Comment: Can you try do the same example but comparing with sysdate ? :)

Comment: Because you're comparing comparable data types (in this case date -> date, timestamp -> timestamp or date -> timestamp) it's very simple @delive. SYSDATE is a date so replace the appropriate date or timestamp with SYSDATE.

Comment: OMG I've been querying Oracle for 20+ years and always hated the TO_DATE syntax.  I'd never seen the literal date until today - it's so clear and simple!  I will not shy from Oracle date filters anymore - thank you!

Answer (score 6):

`to_char` works in its own way.

Always use this format **YYYY-MM-DD** for comparison
instead of **MM-DD-YY** or **DD-MM-YYYY** or any other format.

Answer (score 5):

You can use trunc and to_date as follows:

```
select TO_CHAR (g.FECHA, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') fecha_salida, g.NUMERO_GUIA, g.BOD_ORIGEN, g.TIPO_GUIA, dg.DOC_NUMERO, dg.* 
from ils_det_guia dg, ils_guia g
where dg.NUMERO_GUIA = g.NUMERO_GUIA and dg.TIPO_GUIA = g.TIPO_GUIA and dg.BOD_ORIGEN = g.BOD_ORIGEN
and dg.LAB_CODIGO = 56 
and trunc(g.FECHA) > to_date('01/02/15','DD/MM/YY')
order by g.FECHA;
```

Answer (score 5):

from your query:

```
Select employee_id, count(*) From Employee 
Where to_char(employee_date_hired, 'DD-MON-YY') > '31-DEC-95'
```

i think its not to display the number of employees that are hired after June 20, 1994. if you want show number of employees, you can use:

```
Select count(*) From Employee 
Where to_char(employee_date_hired, 'YYYMMMDDD') > 19940620
```

I think for best practice to compare dates you can use:

```
employee_date_hired > TO_DATE('20-06-1994', 'DD-MM-YYYY');
or
to_char(employee_date_hired, 'YYYMMMDDD') > 19940620;
```

Answer (score -4):

Single quote must be there, since date converted to character.

```
Select employee_id, count(*)
From Employee
Where to_char(employee_date_hired, 'DD-MON-YY') > '31-DEC-95';
```

Comment: This SQL uses an implicit date format, it will not always work.

Comment: It's only working fine for your specific NLS_* settings, it may not work on other clients or servers.  The accepted answer explains why an explicit date format is important.

Comment: This method is comparing strings, not dates.  The second string starts with a "3", so the compare works like "alphabetical order".  Interestingly, this type of compare actually works ( sort-of by accident ) if you use a format like YYYY-MM-DD.  But of course, it's better to compare dates to dates...