# Oracle date to string conversion

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string column COL1 when I am doing this

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(COL1,'dd-mon-yy'), 'mm/dd/yyyy')
FROM TABLE1
```

The data in COL1 is in dd-mon-yy, eg: 27-11-89 and 89 is 1989 but the select returns it as 11/27/2089.

I have to do an inner TO_DATE because if I don't then I am getting an invalid number error (ORA-01722: invalid number)

How can show 1989 instead of 2089? Please help

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> *The data in COL1 is in dd-mon-yy*

No it's not. A `DATE` column does ***not*** have any format. It is only converted (implicitely) to that representation by your SQL client when you display it.

If COL1 is really a `DATE` column using `to_date()` on it is useless because `to_date()` converts a string to a DATE.

You only need to_char(), nothing else:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(col1, 'mm/dd/yyyy') 
FROM TABLE1
```

What happens in your case is that calling `to_date()` converts the `DATE` into a character value (applying the default NLS format) and then converting that back to a DATE. Due to this double implicit conversion some information is lost on the way.

---

**Edit**

So you did make that big mistake to store a DATE in a character column. And that's why you get the problems now.

The best (and to be honest: only sensible) solution is to convert that column to a `DATE`. Then you can convert the values to any rerpresentation that you want without worrying about implicit data type conversion.

But most probably the answer is "*I inherited this model, I have to cope with it*" (it always is, apparently no one ever is responsible for choosing the wrong datatype), then you need to use `RR` instead of `YY`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(COL1,'dd-mm-rr'), 'mm/dd/yyyy')
FROM TABLE1
```

should do the trick. Note that I also changed `mon` to `mm` as your example is `27-11-89` which has a number for the month, not an "word" (like *NOV*)

For more details see the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00215

Comment: Sorry it is a string column. I have edited my question on why I am doing that.

Comment: @Ram: Do ***not*** put dates into character columns. The problem you are having right now, only exists because you did so.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I will try and get the data source changed from char to date col. The dates we get from source are in Y2K string format and needs a user defined function to be converted to a date.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Oracle has this feature to distinguish the millennium years..

As you mentioned, if your column is a varchar, then the below query will yield you 1989..

select to_date(column_name,'dd/mm/rr') from table1;

When the format rr is used in year, the following would be done by oracle.

if rr->00 to 49   ---> result will be 2000 - 2049, 
if rr->50 to 99   ---> result will be 1950 - 1999

Answer (score 0):

If your column is of type *DATE* (as you say), then you don't need to convert it into a string first (in fact you would convert it implicitly to a string first, then explicitly to a date and again explicitly to a string):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(COL1, 'mm/dd/yyyy') FROM TABLE1
```

The date format your seeing for your column is an artifact of the tool your using (TOAD, SQL Developer etc.) and it's language settings.

Comment: Sorry it is a string column. I have edited my question on why I am doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to notice is you are trying to convert a date in mm/dd/yyyy but if you have any plans of comparing this converted date to some other date then make sure to convert it in yyyy-mm-dd format only since to_char literally converts it into a string and with any other format we will get undesired result.
For any more explanation follow this: 
[Comparing Dates in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178292/comparing-dates-in-oracle-sql)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from 
(SELECT TO_CHAR(COL1, 'yyyy-MM-dd') as col1 FROM TABLE1
) T
WHERE col1 ='2021-11-12'
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.