# How can I convert datetime to string in PL SQL?

Tags: plsql

Is it possible to convert a Datetime value to string in PL SQL?
I should to do that to a IF in PL SQL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle date to string conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591546/oracle-date-to-string-conversion)

Answer (score 4):

Use to_char(date, format)

e.g.

Select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY') from dual;

Answer (score 0):

**You can use like this:**

```
SELECT  
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20190811 10:44:11','YYYYMMDD HH24:Mi:SS'),'YYYYMMDD HH24:Mi:SS') YOUR_STRING_DATE
 FROM
DUAL
```