# BIRT REPORTING in I need to remove time for the date

Tags: birt

[image][image]

I need to remove time for the date column I dont why the time is coming can any one help me

Answer (score 0):

You can convert datetime to string in your SQL procedure. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp) you can find the formats.

For example, if you want to convert datetime to format dd-MM-yyyy, use query:

`CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105)`

If you want to sort data using date, leave the actual date in your SQL procedure. This date you will use for sorting, and string for display. Don't use string for sorting because it will use alphanumeric rules.

Comment: i am using oracle sql

Comment: @KeshavRaj Sorry for the late reply.
Maybe this article can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591546/oracle-date-to-string-conversion