# Where clause not working for DATES

Tags: sql, oracle10g

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparing Dates in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178292/comparing-dates-in-oracle-sql)

When I deal with DATE datatype, where clause does not make difference. The following code is displaying ALL the 107  rows. It should have displayed around 5 rows. There is no syntax error either. Where clause is working fine with number, character, etc.

```
    select last_name,hire_date
    from employees
    where hire_date < '01-JAN-90'
```

Comment: @ankitaP- this comparison will work only when the given literal is in the default date format. For all other formats we have to convert the literal to date using TO_DATE function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never rely on implicit conversion. use:

```
where hire_date < to_date('01-JAN-1990', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try a [proper date literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm):

```
select last_name,hire_date
from employees
where hire_date < DATE '1990-01-01'
```

Here's a running example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/782c0/1

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (
  last_name VARCHAR(50),
  hire_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO Employees VALUES ('A', DATE '1985-01-01');
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES ('B', DATE '1986-01-01');
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES ('C', DATE '1987-01-01');
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES ('D', DATE '1988-01-01');
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES ('E', DATE '1989-01-01');
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES ('F', DATE '1990-01-01');
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES ('G', DATE '1991-01-01');
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES ('H', DATE '1992-01-01');
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES ('I', DATE '1993-01-01');
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES ('J', DATE '1994-01-01');
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES ('K', DATE '1995-01-01');
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES ('L', DATE '1996-01-01');
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES ('M', DATE '1997-01-01');
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES ('N', DATE '1998-01-01');


select last_name,hire_date
from employees
where hire_date < DATE '1990-01-01'
```

Comment: Sorry this code is not working.

Comment: @ankitaP I'm sorry, I cannot help you any further unless I know what problem you are seeing or what difference you are expecting.  I have posted the code I used to test my answer.

Comment: My EMPLOYEES table is already existed and it contains 107 rows. The SELECT..FROM..WHERE statement which I written above was not working with DATE as it must not be doing Type Casting Implicitly. Well, I got my answer given by Dazzal. Thanks for helping me. Cheers !!