# Comparing with date in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a column `'creation_date'` which is of type `'date'`, when I am querying my table for distinct records based on `'creation_date'` I am getting 6 records:

```
select distinct creation_date from test_table;
```

output:

```
06-APR-11
06-APR-11
28-MAR-11
06-APR-11
06-APR-11
18-MAR-11
```

In this output 6th April is displayed 4 times even when I used distinct in my query. Also when I am trying to find out all records which are matching with `creation_date` of `6th April 2011` I am not getting any results. Below is my query:

```
select * from  test_table where creation_date = to_date('06-APR-11','DD-MON-YY');
```

Please help me where I am doing wrong in these **two** queries.

Comment: @chaithanya: Most of the database use Timestamp so have a look at it will help u later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is twofold. Firstly the dates almost definitely have time-components. `to_date('06-MAR-11','DD-MON-YY')` is equivalent to `2011/03/06 00:00:00`. If you use the [`TRUNC()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions220.htm#SQLRF06151) function you will be able to see everything for that day:

```
select * 
  from test_table
 where trunc(creation_date) = to_date('06-MAR-11','DD-MON-YY');
```

I would *not* use the MON [datetime format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212). As I explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178292/comparing-dates-in-oracle-sql/10178346#10178346) it depends on your region and settings. It's safer to use a numeric month format model instead. Equally, always specify century as part of the year.

```
where trunc(creation_date) = to_date('06-03-YY11','DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Your second problem is almost definitely your [NLS_DATE_FORMAT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/initparams145.htm#REFRN10119); it appears to not take into account the time, hence why you see 4 identical dates. This only governs the manner in which data is *displayed* not how it is stored.

You can change this using something like:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = "DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS"
```

If I set up a test environment using the following:

```
create table test_table ( creation_date date );
insert into test_table values ( sysdate );
insert into test_table values ( sysdate - 0.01 );
alter session set nls_date_format = "YYYY/MM/DD";
```

You can see the data returned does not include time (though SYSDATE does):

```
SQL> select * from test_table;

CREATION_D
----------
2013/04/12
2013/04/12
```

Altering the NLS_DATE_FORMAT and performing the same SELECT, you now get a time component:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = "YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS";

Session altered.

SQL> select * from test_table;

CREATION_DATE
-------------------
2013/04/12 12:48:41
2013/04/12 12:34:17
```

Lastly, when trying to select today's date alone no rows will be returned:

```
SQL> select *
  2    from test_table
  3   where creation_date = to_date('20130412','yyyymmdd');

no rows selected
```

But, when using `TRUNC()` to compare on only the date portion of the field you get all your rows again:

```
SQL> select *
  2    from test_table
  3   where trunc(creation_date) = to_date('20130412','yyyymmdd');

CREATION_DATE
-------------------
2013/04/12 12:48:41
2013/04/12 12:34:17
```

To actually answer your second question, if you want unique dates you can re-use the `TRUNC()` function:

```
select distinct trunc(creation_date)
  from test_table
```

Answer (score 1):

The DATE datatype stores the year (including the century), the month, the day, the hours, the minutes, and the seconds (after midnight). You must also consider this.