# Oracle Date format

Tags: oracle, date

Oracle 11g documentation says that default date format is DD-MON-YYYY, which means that if I insert date to a date column using:

```
insert into table t values(1, '02-JAN-2013')
```

and then select it

```
select * from t
```

it should display as 02-JAN-2013 whereas in reality it displays date as 01/02/2013.

Why his discrepancy or am I missing something.

Ref. http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-time.html

FYI. I am using PL/SQL Developer for this experiment.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really a default date format for the product, the [reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/initparams145.htm) states that the default for `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` at system level is based on `NLS_TERRITORY`. Though [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25518/adfns_sqltypes.htm#sthref271) says the 'standard' is `DD-MON-RR', and I think that's what you get if you don't specify a value at database level, at least on the platforms I've worked on.

When you create a new database the initialisation parameters can include a specific `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, and that can be changed later too.

But the system-level `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` can be overridden by the client, the session, or in a `TO_CHAR` call. You can look in `v$nls_parameters` to see the system value, and `nls_session_parameters` to see your current session value. You can change that with `alter session` if you want to.

I'm pretty sure you'll find that PL/SQL Developer is setting the session `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` to `MM/DD/YYYY` somewhere in its preferences.

Generally it's better to not rely on that value at all, and always use an explicit format mask for display, e.g. `TO_CHAR(<column>, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`.

There's more on `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` in the globalisation guide [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#i1006547) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm#i1006817); and a bit about date display [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/tablecls.htm#sthref145); and an overview of the date format model elements [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#i34924)

Comment: If this is the case then why I have to use specific format while comparision of dates: Eg.                                                      select si.effective_date from search_instance si where si.effective_date > '26-JUN-2013' order by si.effective_date   . If instead of '26-JUN-2013' I use '06/26/2013' it will say 'Not a valid Month'.

Comment: To answer your comment please read my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178292/comparing-dates-in-oracle-sql/10178346#10178346) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970277/comparing-with-date-in-oracle-sql/15970516#15970516) (I'm sure Alex has as many) @user204069... You're ***not*** comparing dates there, you're comparing strings. _Always_ explicitly convert strings to a date for date comparisons.

Comment: @user204069 - what is your session value? You're doing an implicit conversion from a string to a date, which you should avoid as it's ambiguous. You should use `to_date('06/26/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY')`. Or possibly `date '2013-06-26'`, using an ANSI date literal.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of `NSL_DATE_FORMAT` that depends of `NLS_TERRITORY`

Give a look to: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams122.htm

Comment: If this is the case then why I have to use specific format while comparision of dates: Eg. select si.effective_date from search_instance si where si.effective_date > '26-JUN-2013' order by si.effective_date . If instead of '26-JUN-2013' I use '06/26/2013' it will say 'Not a valid Month'.

Comment: I try to use always the ansi date format: 'YYMMDDHHMISS' with this, i do not have to check what format the DB use.  Then i can use something like `si.effective_date > '20130626000000'`