# Oracle SQL Function return date format

Tags: oracle, function, date, plsql, date-format

I have small problem on Oracle PL-SQL,

I created a function

that at the end looks like this :

```
 wynik := concat(miesiac,concat(dzien,rok));
 w_date := TO_DATE(wynik);
 return w_date;
```

It works fine but it returns date in format MM/DD/YYYY, and i would want to return in format of DD MONTH YYYY, how can i reach that without alter sesion on global settings?

I tried messing with:

```
w_date := TO_DATE(wynik,'DD MONTH YYYY');
```

But it gives me errors....

Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle Date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326469/oracle-date-format)

Comment: The function does not return the date in any format at all -- it returns a DATE datatype, which is unambiguous. When you display it, it has to be converted to a human readable string, and that display format is configurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TO_DATE` converts string to date and it is rendered to output using default date format definied for session. If you want to display it differently use `TO_CHAR` function or change default format.

Example `TO_CHAR` usage:

```
TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD MONTH YYYY')
```

To change default format:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD MONTH YYYY';
```

Comment: The problem is that the guiideline of this function is to return date variable, of course with TO_CHAR it works perfectly fine but i need to return as date, as shown on below code.

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Pesel_dataur(p_pesel IN CHAR)
    return date`

So the only option for correct result with proper format is to Alter  global settings?

Comment: So just return `w_date`. What is the problem? You can return date and relay on NLS_DATE_FORMAT  or return string and provide custom format. I don't see another option.

Comment: And there is no such thing as proper format for date. Whole date is stored internally despite NLS_DATE_FORMAT. NLS_DATE_FORMAT is only used to display DATE object in readable way when you do select.

Answer (score 1):

Internally, the `DATE` is stored as a number, not as a string, so neither the string converted to the `DATE`, nor the format date model used (explicitly or implicitly, from session parameter) during the creation of the variable, has anything to do with the way a `DATE` variable is presented to the user.

To show a `DATE` variable as a string, the `TO_CHAR` function should be used, and the format mask used:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD MONTH YYYY') AS val FROM dual;
```

```
VAL                                                
----------------------------------------------------
14 LISTOPAD    2013
```

To suppress the extra blank spaces, use the `fm` modifier:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD fmMONTH YYYY') AS val FROM dual;
```

```
VAL                                                
----------------------------------------------------
14 LISTOPAD 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

```
w_date := TO_CHAR(wynik,'DD MONTH YYYY');
```