# using sql query with group by date

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select, group-by

I'm trying to write this query to retrieve No. of records grouped by date:

```
SELECT system_date,count (is_paid)
  FROM TPWEB.TP_CLIENT_TENDER_TRANS
  where system_date between '1-DEC-12' and '31-DEC-12'
  group by system_date
```

But, I got result without grouping such as:

```
01-DEC-12   1
01-DEC-12   1
01-DEC-12   1
01-DEC-12   1
```

what is wrong...

Comment: show us the original data

Comment: that will come up with this query `SELECT system_date, is_paid FROM TPWEB.TP_CLIENT_TENDER_TRANS
  where system_date between '1-DEC-12' and '31-DEC-12'`

Comment: Its not clear what your table schema is, but I suspect that system_date is a datetime field, not a date field, this means that your grouping is being done incorrectly and also includes the time portion of the field.

Answer (score 12):

As is [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/tablecls.htm#CNCPT88810) the DATE datatype is a datetime and thus stores the hour, minute and second in addition to the attributes you'd, more reasonably expect, in a datatype with this name. If you want to count over a day you need to remove the time portion of your date. It is the default behaviour of [`TRUNC()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions220.htm#SQLRF51943), so to do this `trunc(<date>)` is all you need.

It's worth noting two things at this point:

1. I'm assuming `system_date` is a column in your table and not a misunderstanding of [SYSDATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions191.htm#SQLRF51846)
2. Your between clause is completely incorrect, dangerously so.

   By the way your dates have been represented it appears as though your NLS_DATE_FORMAT is DD-MON-YYYY (see [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970277/comparing-with-date-in-oracle-sql/15970516#15970516) for more details). This means that when you implicitly convert a date into a character it is converted in this format.

   You're not using either a [datetime literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062) or an [explicit conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions203.htm#SQLRF51886) of the values you're comparing to, which means your date is being implicitly converted to a character. However, when you do the comparison you'll find that things aren't always as they seem. Character comparison is, normally, binary; this means that the 10<sup>th</sup> of February is not between the 10<sup>th</sup> January and the 10<sup>th</sup> March; "March" is smaller than "January".

   *Always* explicitly convert dates and *always* use dates when doing date comparisons.

Putting all of this together your query becomes:

```
select trunc(system_date), count(is_paid)`
  from TPWEB.TP_CLIENT_TENDER_TRANS
 where system_date between date '2012-12-01' and date '2012-12-31'
 group by trunc(system_date)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use trunc function, the DATE datatype holds the time with it, so using trunc we can truncate time. Below query works!

```
SELECT trunc(system_date),count (is_paid)
  FROM TPWEB.TP_CLIENT_TENDER_TRANS
  where system_date between '1-DEC-12' and '31-DEC-12'
  group by trunc(system_date);
```

Answer (score 1):

`DATE` columns in Oracle contain precision up to milliseconds, not just the date. If you're only interested in the date itself, you should `TRUNC` it to remove hours, minutes, etc.:

```
SELECT   system_date,COUNT (is_paid)
FROM     TPWEB.TP_CLIENT_TENDER_TRANS
WHERE    system_date BETWEEN '1-DEC-12' AND '31-DEC-12'
GROUP BY TRUNC(system_date, 'DD-MON-YY')
```

Comment: This is incorrect. A `DATE` is represented by 7 bytes consisting of 1-byte each for century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and seconds; it only stores integer seconds (not milli-seconds). If you have fractional seconds then you have a `TIMESTAMP` data type which can store between 0 and 9 decimal digits for the seconds (depending on if you use `TIMESTAMP(0)` or `TIMESTAMP(9)` or something in between).

Answer (score -2):

This works for me:

```
select DT_FECHA_DESDE,DT_FECHA_HASTA
from (SELECT TRUNC(DT_FECHA_DESDE)as DT_FECHA_DESDE,TRUNC(DT_FECHA_HASTA) as DT_FECHA_HASTA
FROM TBL1
WHERE run='3456'
order by DT_FECHA_DESDE)  
group by DT_FECHA_DESDE,DT_FECHA_HASTA
```