# Group By function not doing GROUP BY using WITH CTE Statement in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, group-by

I have a procedure which is mostly used to `GROUP BY` data and present in a single line. But with the below code, I am able to see same `SPANID` multiple times. Image below for reference.

[image]

Also below is the query for same.

```
WITH
   temp
   AS
      (  SELECT TO_CHAR (tfc.spanid) spanid,              
                TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_code) AS maint_zone_code,
                TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_name) AS maint_zone_name,
                SUM (tfc.mho_handover_cert) AS ne_length,
                tfc.created_date AS offered_date          
           FROM app_lco.tbl_fip_checklist tfc
          WHERE     LENGTH (TRIM (tfc.spanid)) > 8
                AND LENGTH (TRIM (tfc.spanid)) < 21
                AND tfc.status = 'APPROVED'
       GROUP BY TO_CHAR (tfc.spanid),                     
                TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_code),
                TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_name),
                tfc.created_date              
       MINUS
       SELECT TO_CHAR (bb.link_id) AS span_id,
              TO_CHAR (bb.maintenancezonecode) AS maint_zone_code,
              TO_CHAR (bb.maintenancezonename) AS maint_zone_name,
              maint_zone_ne_span_length AS ne_length,
              bb.created_date
         FROM tbl_fiber_inv_jobs bb
        WHERE span_type = 'INTRACITY')
  SELECT spanid,
         maint_zone_code,
         maint_zone_name,
         SUM (ne_length),
         offered_date
    FROM temp
GROUP BY spanid,
         maint_zone_code,
         maint_zone_name,
         offered_date;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using sql query with group by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171768/using-sql-query-with-group-by-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `CREATED_DATE` contains date and time component (which is not *set* to midnight) so - although screenshot suggests that those dates *are* the same, maybe it is just the way they are displayed.

Therefore, would `trunc` help?

```
WITH
   temp
   AS
      (  SELECT TO_CHAR (tfc.spanid) spanid,
                TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_code) AS maint_zone_code,
                TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_name) AS maint_zone_name,
                SUM (tfc.mho_handover_cert) AS ne_length,
                TRUNC (tfc.created_date) AS offered_date       --> TRUNC here ...
           FROM app_lco.tbl_fip_checklist tfc
          WHERE     LENGTH (TRIM (tfc.spanid)) > 8
                AND LENGTH (TRIM (tfc.spanid)) < 21
                AND tfc.status = 'APPROVED'
       GROUP BY TO_CHAR (tfc.spanid),
                TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_code),
                TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_name),
                TRUNC(tfc.created_date)
       MINUS
       SELECT TO_CHAR (bb.link_id) AS span_id,
              TO_CHAR (bb.maintenancezonecode) AS maint_zone_code,
              TO_CHAR (bb.maintenancezonename) AS maint_zone_name,
              maint_zone_ne_span_length AS ne_length,
              TRUNC (bb.created_date)                          --> ... and here
         FROM tbl_fiber_inv_jobs bb
        WHERE span_type = 'INTRACITY')
  SELECT spanid,
         maint_zone_code,
         maint_zone_name,
         SUM (ne_length),
         offered_date
    FROM temp
GROUP BY spanid,
         maint_zone_code,
         maint_zone_name,
         offered_date;
```

Comment: yes now it worked perfectly, what was it not working that time..

Comment: Great! I'm glad you fixed it.

Comment: It is not necessary (as the following `MINUS` de-duplicates the data), but it would be more *meaningfull* to also `group by` on truncated `tfc.created_date`

Comment: with your code, it still generating the same `spanid` multiple or thrice times..

Comment: any update @littlefoot: ???

Comment: The final SELECT statements aggregates data on NE_LENGTH, which means that columns - which are part of GROUP BY clause: SPANID, MAINT_ZONE_CODE, MAINT_ZONE_NAME,OFFERED_DATE - cause duplicates. I can't tell which one. OFFERED_DATE is now the least suspicious as it is truncated to DATE (i.e. time component is removed). Unless you post some sample data that illustrates the problem, I wouldn't know what causes the issue. Try to TRUNC all other columns; maybe they have some extra spaces or non-printable characters. Can't tell.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data-type that consists of 7-bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It **ALWAYS** has those components and it is **NEVER** stored in any particular human-readable format.

The *client application* (i.e. SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, Java, C#, etc.) may chose to display the binary date in any format it choses and some opt to default to not display the time component; that does **NOT** mean that the time component does not exist.

When you use `GROUP BY` you will group values that are identical; since a `DATE` contains year-to-second components then it will group them based on **ALL** the components including the seconds.

If you want to see the full date then use `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
WITH
   temp
   AS
      (  SELECT TO_CHAR (tfc.spanid) spanid,              
                TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_code) AS maint_zone_code,
                TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_name) AS maint_zone_name,
                SUM (tfc.mho_handover_cert) AS ne_length,
                tfc.created_date AS offered_date          
           FROM app_lco.tbl_fip_checklist tfc
          WHERE     LENGTH (TRIM (tfc.spanid)) > 8
                AND LENGTH (TRIM (tfc.spanid)) < 21
                AND tfc.status = 'APPROVED'
       GROUP BY TO_CHAR (tfc.spanid),                     
                TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_code),
                TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_name),
                tfc.created_date              
       MINUS
       SELECT TO_CHAR (bb.link_id) AS span_id,
              TO_CHAR (bb.maintenancezonecode) AS maint_zone_code,
              TO_CHAR (bb.maintenancezonename) AS maint_zone_name,
              maint_zone_ne_span_length AS ne_length,
              bb.created_date
         FROM tbl_fiber_inv_jobs bb
        WHERE span_type = 'INTRACITY')
  SELECT spanid,
         maint_zone_code,
         maint_zone_name,
         SUM (ne_length),
         TO_CHAR(offered_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as offered_date
    FROM temp
GROUP BY spanid,
         maint_zone_code,
         maint_zone_name,
         offered_date;
```

If you want to only use the date component and not the time component then use `TRUNC` to set the time components to midnight so that all values on a day will be grouped together:

```sql
WITH
   temp
   AS
      (  SELECT TO_CHAR (tfc.spanid) spanid,              
                TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_code) AS maint_zone_code,
                TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_name) AS maint_zone_name,
                SUM (tfc.mho_handover_cert) AS ne_length,
                TRUNC(tfc.created_date) AS offered_date          
           FROM app_lco.tbl_fip_checklist tfc
          WHERE     LENGTH (TRIM (tfc.spanid)) > 8
                AND LENGTH (TRIM (tfc.spanid)) < 21
                AND tfc.status = 'APPROVED'
       GROUP BY TO_CHAR (tfc.spanid),                     
                TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_code),
                TO_CHAR (tfc.mz_name),
                TRUNC(tfc.created_date)             
       MINUS
       SELECT TO_CHAR (bb.link_id) AS span_id,
              TO_CHAR (bb.maintenancezonecode) AS maint_zone_code,
              TO_CHAR (bb.maintenancezonename) AS maint_zone_name,
              maint_zone_ne_span_length AS ne_length,
              TRUNC(bb.created_date)
         FROM tbl_fiber_inv_jobs bb
        WHERE span_type = 'INTRACITY')
  SELECT spanid,
         maint_zone_code,
         maint_zone_name,
         SUM (ne_length),
         offered_date
    FROM temp
GROUP BY spanid,
         maint_zone_code,
         maint_zone_name,
         offered_date;
```