# JDBCTemplate delete row with date only as criteria

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to delete from Oracle some users using Birthday as criterium in Java.

Table in ORACLE:

```
create table users{
..
birthday DATE not null,
...
}
```

Data stored looks like:

```
user1, 17.03.1976
user2, 28.09.1968
```

I need now to delete data using JDBCTemplates (birthday is provided from related framework as java.util.Date)

```
private void deleteUser(java.util.Date birthdayUtil)
{
  java.sql.Date birthday = new java.sql.Date(birthdayUtil.getTime());
  String sql = "DELETE FROM USERS WHERE birthday = ?";
  jdbcTemplate.update(sql, birthday);
}
```

However, no data are deleted, even if Date is set properly to values available in database.

Any idea?

Comment: Related -- it may answer your question? [Group By function not doing GROUP BY using WITH CTE Statement in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77126985/group-by-function-not-doing-group-by-using-with-cte-statement-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the field birthday in the Oracle database.

If the field is created as a timestamp in the Oracle database, you must work with a time range.

Attention, this is Scala code, but it should work similarly with Java.

// Expand the fields to include the time:

```
val birthday_from = s"${birthday} 00:00:00"
val birthday_to = s"${birthday} 23:59:59"
```

Or create two LocalDateTime-Fields.

// SQL - The birthday must fall between the two timestamps: 28.09.1968 00:00:00 and 28.09.1968 23:59:59

```
where birthday >= TO_DATE(?, 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
  and birthday <= TO_DATE(?, 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
```