# Converting a MySQL query to Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle, database-migration

The following query was working fine in MySQL:

```
SELECT
  total,
  status.nome
FROM status
  INNER JOIN (SELECT count(*) AS total,
                     status_id
                FROM [log]
               WHERE evento_id = '21'
                 AND data BETWEEN '02/09/2013 00:00:00' AND '02/09/2013 23:59:59'
               GROUP BY status_id) AS groupedTable
ON groupedTable.status_id = status.id;
```

but when I try to run it in Oracle, i get the following error message:

> ORA-00903: invalid table name

If I change the query as:

```
SELECT 
    total, status.nome 
FROM 
    status 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT count(*) as total, status_id 
          FROM log
        WHERE evento_id = '21' 
          AND data BETWEEN '02/09/2013 00:00:00' AND '02/09/2013 23:59:59' 
        GROUP BY status_id) AS groupedTable 
    ON groupedTable.status_id = status.id;
```

i get this error message instead:

```
ORA-00905: keyword not found
```

I think the problem is in the `log` table but I am not able to convert it and make it work in Oracle. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Please read about how to compare dates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178292/comparing-dates-in-oracle-sql/10178346#10178346; you've not here which will cause all sorts of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you were right to remove the square brackets from the `[log]` table. The square brackets are not a valid delimiter, and they're not valid characters for a table name.

Second, Oracle doesn't like the `AS` in `SELECT ... FROM myTable AS myAlias`. It allows `AS` for column aliases, but not for table aliases, so drop the `As` in `As groupedTable`.

Third, your date format is probably invalid. If it isn't, it's still a potential failure point. Oracle's [`DATETIME` literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ) format is like this (MySQL supports this too):

```
DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'
```

Further down on the referenced page, you'll see that the `TIMESTAMP` literal (at least as far as you need it) is:

```
TIMESTAMP 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'
```

The hours should use the "24-hour" clock, so 4PM is `16:00:00`.

I'd recommend changing the date logic to this:

```
AND data >= DATE '2013-02-09' AND data < '2013-02-10'
```

Or it you're keen to use `BETWEEN` here you could go with the wordier option:

```
AND data BETWEEN DATE '2013-02-09' AND TIMESTAMP '2013-02-09 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Thanks, now it's works... SELECT total, status.nome FROM status INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) as total, status_id FROM log WHERE evento_id = '21' AND data >= DATE '2013-09-02' AND data <= DATE '2013-09-03' GROUP BY status_id) ON status_id = status.id

Comment: Excellent! But note the logic in your original question looked for dates of any time on `9/2/2013`. To do that, you need to end the `WHERE` with `... AND data < DATE '2013-09-03` (less than, not less than or equal to like in your comment). If you use `<=` then a date of 9/3/2013 at midnight will be included.

Comment: Yeah, I have seen that now... i changed to SELECT total, status.nome FROM status INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) as total, status_id FROM log WHERE evento_id = '21' AND data >= TIMESTAMP '2013-09-02 00:00:00' AND data <= TIMESTAMP '2013-09-02 23:59:59' GROUP BY status_id) ON status_id = status.id