# Oracle SQL query for fetch values by greater than statement on dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote following simple select query to fetch data, which is greater than the particular given date.

```
select *
from   XVIIX.emp_tasks
where  TASK_START_DATE > to_Date('30-MAR-18','DD-MM-YYYY');
```

But the result is not what is expected from that.

[image]

Can someone explain me what is the root cause for this behavior?

Comment: Typo: Use `to_Date('30-MAR-2018', 'DD-MM-YYYY')`

Comment: This cannot work. to_Date('30-MAR-18','DD-MM-YYYY'); MAR cannot be converted into march using MM format. You should have got an error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178292/comparing-dates-in-oracle-sql read this question you will understand the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is converting two digit years to four-digit years.  It is better to use explicit date literals:

```
where task_start_date > date '2018-03-30'
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with the format model of `to_Date('30-MAR-18','DD-MM-YYYY');`

The month is expressed as a 3 character month, but the format model for month is `MM`, which expects a month number, `MON` is for an abbreviated month name.

`YYYY` is expecting a 4 digit year, you have supplied two, either supply 4, or change the format model to `YY`

Comment: Thank you for your advice. That solved my problem.