# Oracle: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I've got a problem with my database. I have created table:

```
CREATE TABLE TOURNAMENT
  (
    TOURNAMENT_ID   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    DATE            DATE NOT NULL,
    CITY            VARCHAR2 (100 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    PRIZEPOOL       NUMBER (18,2) NOT NULL,
    COUNTRY         VARCHAR2 (100 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    ARENA           VARCHAR2 (100 CHAR),
    SHOP_ID         INTEGER,
    PRODUCTION_ID   INTEGER NOT NULL
  );

ALTER TABLE TOURNAMENT ADD CONSTRAINT TOURNAMENT_PK PRIMARY KEY ( TOURNAMENT_ID ) ;
```

And when I try to insert a row with:

```
prompt Tabulka TOURNAMENT

insert into TOURNAMENT (TOURNAMENT_ID, DATE, CITY, PRIZEPOOL, COUNTRY, ARENA, SHOP_ID, PRODUCTION_ID)
values (1, 08-OCT-2015, 'Moscow', 15000, 'Russia', NULL, 1, 3);
```

I get an error message:

> ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Does anybody know what this could mean?

Comment: Perhaps you merely need quotes around the date constant.

Comment: Firstly, you cannot have a column named DATE in a table, rename this to something like TOURNAMENT_DATE

Comment: Yes, That was it. Thank you very much.

Comment: To explain the error message, the parser is rejecting the word `OCT` in your `values` clause. It has interpreted it as a column name (similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/10178292/230471), and column names are not allowed in the `values` clause of `insert`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work -

```
CREATE TABLE TOURNAMENT
  (
    TOURNAMENT_ID   INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    TOURNAMENT_DATE       DATE NOT NULL ,
    CITY       VARCHAR2 (100 CHAR) NOT NULL ,
    PRIZEPOOL   NUMBER (18,2) NOT NULL ,
    COUNTRY        VARCHAR2 (100 CHAR) NOT NULL ,
    ARENA       VARCHAR2 (100 CHAR) ,
    SHOP_ID   INTEGER ,
    PRODUCTION_ID INTEGER NOT NULL
  ) ;
ALTER TABLE TOURNAMENT ADD CONSTRAINT TOURNAMENT_PK PRIMARY KEY ( TOURNAMENT_ID ) ;



insert into TOURNAMENT (TOURNAMENT_ID, TOURNAMENT_DATE, CITY, PRIZEPOOL, COUNTRY, ARENA, SHOP_ID, PRODUCTION_ID) values (1, TO_DATE('08-OCT-2015','DD-MON-YYYY'), 'Moscow', 15000, 'Russia', NULL, 1, 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are writing a date value the wrong way; one way could be with ANSI format:

```
INSERT INTO TOURNAMENT(
                       TOURNAMENT_ID,
                       DATE_,
                       CITY,
                       PRIZEPOOL,
                       COUNTRY,
                       ARENA,
                       SHOP_ID,
                       PRODUCTION_ID
                      )
     VALUES (
             1,
             DATE '2015-10-08',
             'Moscow',
             15000,
             'Russia',
             NULL,
             1,
             3
            );
```

Or, if you want to keep the format you showed, with a `to_date`:

```
to_date('08-OCT-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Besides, `DATE` is a reserved word, you'd better avoid it to name table columns.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I didn't have 'DATE' there. All the variables were named in my slavic language, but since i wanted you to understand what i'ts supposed to do, I translated the whole table :)