# SQL Query to fetch data after 01-01-2022

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, bi-publisher

I have a date coming in the format 2022-05-26T13:50:44.000Z, 2018-10-05T18:14:00.000Z. I want the date to be picked after 2022 only from this column. But when I am using the below query it is not working at all.

```
 to_date(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(Paaf.last_update_date),'MM-DD-YYYY'),'MM-DD-YYYY') >= TO_DATE('01-01-2022','MM-DD-YYYY')
```

How to compare the date so that it only the dates after 01-01-2022 are picked

If i do `Paaf.last_update_date like '%2022%'` I am getting the output,
is there anyway I can do '%**Current year**%' for the like to work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing Dates in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178292/comparing-dates-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: no it doesnt. I am still getting the 2018.2019 data

Comment: What data type is the column? And what does "not working at all" mean - do you get an error, or just not the result you want?

Comment: I am getting the data 2018, 2019 , 2020

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. You should read the topic carefully and proceed with your question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to truncate then convert to a string and convert back to a date.

Just compare the `DATE` column to a date literal:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name paaf
WHERE  paaf.last_update_date >= DATE '2022-01-01'
```

If you want dates *after* 2022-01-01 00:00:00 then use `>` rather than `>=`.

Comment: I am still seeing output with 2020, 2018 etc

Comment: I am not sure if its because of timestamps

Comment: If i do like '%2022%' it works. Is there anyway I can put %'current year%'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the date part format to be with timezone.
Using cast and to_utc_timestamp_tz oracle functions in following manner.

with x as (
select CAST(to_utc_timestamp_tz('2022-05-26T13:50:44.000Z') AS DATE) as sample_year from dual
)
select * from x where sample_year > TO_DATE('2021-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD');

Answer (score 0):

Just did some check as below,  it should be able to help.

> ```
> create table paaf(last_update_date timestamp);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into paaf values(TIMESTAMP '2021-12-01 05:30:00');
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> insert into paaf values(TIMESTAMP '2022-12-01 05:30:00');
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> insert into paaf values(DATE '2022-01-01');
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select * from paaf where last_update_date >= TIMESTAMP '2022-01-01 00:00:00';
> ```
>
> ```
> | LAST_UPDATE_DATE          |
> | :------------------------ |
> | 01-DEC-22 05.30.00.000000 |
> | 01-JAN-22 00.00.00.000000 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=da77ee9668d4dc8e1e1ea3e88c690e81)*